# Share Site email not being sent

Tags: email, share

If I share a site the email is not being sent.  This function does work with everything else like if you share a document or a list.  This is happening for all users and all sites. The relays on the email servers are setup correctly.

Comment: This was not answered with the other solution due to the invitation email working for documents and lists.  This is only occurring for if you share a site and it is happening on all site for all users.

Comment: Ok after working with Microsoft we found what was causing the issue.  I was using a codeplex project http://ldapcp.codeplex.com/ to resolve names through adfs.  This was not showing the email address in the metadata.  Once I updated it and added the mapping for email in the metadata then it started to work.  Thank you everyone for you help.

Answer (score 0):

This old question might be the same problem/solution. The Share with email does not use the farm settings as it sends as the currently logged in user, e.g. Joe has shared a site with you. You might need to open up your relay(if using exchange) to allow this send as behavior.

["Share with" e-mail invitations not being sent even though all other e-mails work in On-Premise SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74675/share-with-e-mail-invitations-not-being-sent-even-though-all-other-e-mails-wor)

Comment: This solution does not work for me.  The share function works for document and lists.  Its only happening if you share a site.

Comment: Ok I found my answer.  After working with microsoft we determined it was a codeplex tool I am useing to resolve adfs entries in people search.  I just need to update this code and add the email into the metadata.