# SharePoint 2013 E-Mail Invitation Doesn't Work

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, outgoing-email

Recently I've upgraded our SP2010 farm to SP2013. When sharing sites or others objects with someone, there is a "send e-mail invitation" check-box and it works fine on SP2010 visual sites but it is not working at SP2013 visual sites. I've found a thread like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74675/share-with-e-mail-invitations-not-being-sent-even-though-all-other-e-mails-wor). Does really SP2013 use logged on users credentials to send e-mail? Is there any option to send invitation e-mail using farm account like SP2010 does?

Edit: It can be true. When I logged on with farm account I am able to send e-mail invitation but when I logged on with my personal account I can not. Is there any document about this?

Answer (score 1):

To investigate this issue, **You should first be aware of**

- By default, the `Share` option will be only available for `Site Collection Administrators` regardless the `Outgoing Email settings` is configured or not.
- Once you have configured `Outgoing Email settings`, the `Share` option will be available for all users.
- Only the users with `Manage Permission` will be able to `Grant Permission`, so they will be able to  Share the sites without any issue like `send e-mail invitation`.

[image]

[image]

---

**So in your case,** to be able to `send e-mail invitation`, you should make sure that

- You have configured `Outgoing Email settings`.

> **To configured the `Outgoing Email settings` for a web application go to**
>
> - Central Admin > System Settings > E-Mail and Text Messages (SMS) > Configure outgoing e-mail settings.
>
> [image]

- The Personal account has at least `Manage Permission` to be able to Grant permission.

**Otherwise,** you should check with your Exchange Administrator to make sure that there is no restriction to send an email with your personal account.

Comment: Outgoing e-mail configurations are okay @M.Qassas. All e-mails works fine. I'm also a site collection administrator and I am not able to send invitation e-mail. When I use farm account, I am able to send. It maybe because of SP2013 architecture but I couldn't find any documents about this.