# "Outgoing E-Mail Settings" is working well on some operations, while it is not sending emails on other. inside my sharepoint on-premises farm 2013

Tags: 2013, administration, sharepoint-on-prem, notifications, outgoing-email

I have SharePoint farm 2013 on-premises.and i configure the "Outgoing E-Mail Settings" as follow:-

[image]

Now currently the following operations will be sending emails correctly from the above address "`sp-noreply:***.com`":-

- any user who define a user notification on a list or on an item, will receive and email accordingly.
- if i am sending emails from workflow 2010 or workflow 2013.
- emails inside event receivers.
- follow a user will send an email to the user that someone start following him.

but for these 2 actions no emails are being sent:-

1. If userA define to receive an email when someone mentioned him, as follow:-

[image]

then no email will be sent to userA, when let say UserB mention UserA in a newsfeed area.

2. also for the invitation email, when you add a user to a security group, as follow:-

[image]

**Then the user will ONLY receive email if the system account add him, or a user who have "Manage Permission" permission**. But if a user with contribute permission add another user to the group no email will be sent.

now i am not sure what the above indicate about the source of the problem ? is it something inside sharepoint or it is something inside exchnage server or other components ? and what i can do to know the exact source of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem in the last few weeks. SharePoint 2013 are using currently logged on users account to send invitation e-mails and if the user who logged on SharePoint has no permissions to send e-mail using relay, e-mail will not be sent. So I guess your farm account has relay permission and able to send e-mail but users not.

[Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226517/sharepoint-2013-e-mail-invitation-doesnt-work) is my question about same problem and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74675/share-with-e-mail-invitations-not-being-sent-even-though-all-other-e-mails-wor) is another thread.

If you find any further details about problem, please inform me.

Comment: @newbiew thanks a lot for your reply and the links you provided.. now based on the links you provided, and for testing purposes i modify the users permissions inside sharepoint and i grant the Contributor users "Manage Permissions" , now contributor users will be sending emails when they invite some one to a security group, so seems the problem for sending invitation emails is fixed.. but of course i do not want to allow contributor users to have the "Manage Permissions" .. so now not sure who to fix this? is it something inside sharepoint or inside exchange ?

Comment: It's good to hear that. I couldn't find any document about this and still I can not send invitation e-mail even if I am a site collection administrator. If you solve this issue granting "Manage Permissions" to contributors and did not change anything at exchange side, it looks like something inside SharePoint. I really am not sure what the real problem is.

Comment: now seems your problem and mine problem are different. because in my case site admins will always have an invitation emails being sent when they add users to a group... i think the problem in my case is that for users to be able to send invitation emails, then they need to have "Manage Permission" permission assigned to them through a sharepoint group .. now my problem is that i do not want users to have this high-level permission. so not sure if there is a setting within sharepoint or exchnage to allow non-admin users to send invitation emails without the need to grant them "Manage Permission