# "Send an Email Invitation" will only be sending emails if the system account add users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, email, administration, exchange-server

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 on-premises farm. and i am facing this problem when group owner users add other users to the group and they check the "Send an Email Invitation" checkbox, where no emails will be sent.

Here is the full scenario:-

1. i have a team site, which have a group named "Team Site Members", and i define that the group owner is the group itself. and that only group owner can modify the group membership. here is the group settings:-

[image]

2. now when a group member add a user to the group, and he chose to send him an invitation email, as follow:-

[image]

3. **the user will be added, but no email will be sent.**
4. now if i login using the system account, and i add a user, the user will receive an invitation email.

so not sure what could be causing this problem?  is it a setting inside sharepoint or inside exchnage server  related to permisions ?

Answer (score 0):

The "share with" function uses the email address of the current user.

For this issue, make sure the user has the valid email address.

Here is a similar thread for your reference:

["Share with" e-mail invitations not being sent even though all other e-mails work in On-Premise SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74675/share-with-e-mail-invitations-not-being-sent-even-though-all-other-e-mails-wor)

Comment: but the user who is sharing this have a valid email address ..

Comment: can you advice further on this as the user have a valid email address